# Code is working slow - performance issue in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file-comparison, filecompare

I have file which has 4 columns with, separated values. I need only first column only so I have read file then split that line with, separated and store it in one list variable called first_file_list.

I have another file which has 6 columns with, separated values. My requirement is read first column of first row of file and check that string is exist in list called first_file_list. If that is exist then copy that line to new file.

My first file has approx. 6 million records and second file has approx. 4.5 million records. Just to check the performance of my code instead of 4.5 million I have put only 100k records in second file and to process the 100k record code takes approx. 2.5 hours.

Following is my logic for this:

```
first_file_list = []

with open("c:\first_file.csv") as first_f:
    next(first_f)  # Ignoring first row as it is header and I don't need that
    temp = first_f.readlines()
    for x in temp:
        first_file_list.append(x.split(',')[0])
first_f.close()

with open("c:\second_file.csv") as second_f:
    next(second_f)
    second_file_co = second_f.readlines()
second_f.close()

out_file = open("c:\output_file.csv", "a")
for x in second_file_co:
    if x.split(',')[0] in first_file_list:
        out_file.write(x)
out_file.close()
```

Can you please help me to get to know that what I am doing wrong here so that my code take this much time to compare 100k records? or can you suggest better way to do this in Python.

Comment: Make `first_file_list` a `set` where each entry is a delimited string rather than a `list`.

Comment: By the way, using the `with` statement means you don't have to call `.close()` on open file objects.

Comment: can you add samples of the 2 files to the post?

Comment: You can iterate over the file directly (`for x in first_f`); there's no need to read the entire file into memory first.

Comment: By "lac", do you mean "lakh" (100,000)?

Comment: I'd suggest not using "Lac" or more correctly "lakh" since it is not well know AFAIK outside of India/certain regions.  I like English and it is THE language--learn it well (which you have not done yet BTW) please, you'll be glad you did.  :-)

Comment: Lac means lakh. 1 Lakh = 1,00,000

Comment: I would also recommend not using the indian way of doing numbers in 2+2+3 digits. That will definitely cause people to misread them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `set` for fast membership checking.
Also, there's no need to copy the contents of the entire file to memory. You can just iterate over the remaining contents of the file.

```
first_entries = set()
with open("c:\first_file.csv") as first_f:
    next(first_f)
    for line in first_f:
        first_entries.add(line.split(',')[0])

with open("c:\second_file.csv") as second_f:
    with open("c:\output_file.csv", "a") as out_file:
        next(second_f)
        for line in second_f:
            if line.split(',')[0] in first_entries:
                out_file.write(line)
```

Additionally, I noticed you called `.close()` on file objects that were opened with the `with` statement. Using `with` (context managers) means all the clean up is done after you exit its context. So it handles the `.close()` for you.

Comment: It just takes 20 seconds to complete the file with 45 Lakh records. 45Lakh = 45,00,000

Answer (score 3):

work with sets - see below

```
first_file_values = set()
second_file_values = set()

with open("c:\first_file.csv") as first_f:
    next(first_f)
    temp = first_f.readlines()
    for x in temp:
        first_file_values.add(x.split(',')[0])

with open("c:\second_file.csv") as second_f:
    next(second_f)
    second_file_co = second_f.readlines()
    for x in second_file_co:
        second_file_values.add(x.split(',')[0])

with open("c:\output_file.csv", "a") as out_file:
    for x in second_file_values:
        if x in first_file_values:
            out_file.write(x)
```

Comment: Good new! Can you explain what `Lakh` is?

Comment: 45Lakh = 45,00,000